# Need to decrease each list element by 1 from an existing list and append it to a new list

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code I need help with:

```
import random
def GetUserInput():

    numStacks = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 45 (inclusive): "))
    while numStacks < 1 or numStacks > 45:
        print("Number is invalid.")
        return numStacks

    createInitialStacks(numStacks)

def createInitialStacks(numStacks):       
    print("Number of stacks:", numStacks)
    stacks = []
    cards = 45

    for card in range(numStacks - 1):
        value = random.randint(1, (cards + 1) - numStacks)
        stacks.append(value)
        numStacks -= 1
        cards -= value
    stacks.append(cards + 1 - numStacks)         

    print("Stack =",stacks)

def playRound(stacks):
    stacksResult = []
    stacksResult = [x-1 for x in stacks if x > 1]
    print("New Stack =",stacksResult)
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter an integer between 1 and 45 (inclusive): 4
Number of stacks: 4
Stack = [6, 30, 4, 5]
```

The output should look like this:

```
Enter an integer between 1 and 45 (inclusive): 4
Number of stacks: 4
Stack = [6, 30, 4, 5]
New Stack = [5, 29, 3, 4]
```

Also, if there are any zeros in the new stack, they need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

stacksResult = [x-1 for x in stacks if x > 1]